# Website keeps redirecting to index.htm for some reason

Tags: redirect

I moved a client's website from being hosted in-house to a Godaddy server.  The website was built in the early 2000s and wasn't changed until my redesign this week (I think it was pure HTML/CSS).  When you go to [www.broncomfg.net](http://www.broncomfg.net), it always redirects to [www.broncomfg.net/Home.htm](http://www.broncomfg.net/Home.htm) and there is no index.html, so I get a 404 error. This is a WordPress site so that shouldn't be happening.  I cannot figure out why this is happening for the life of me.  The .htaccess file is the standard one that WordPress creates, I have not modified it.  Can someone help me figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my computer.  I needed to flush the DNS (ipconfig /flushdns in cmd.exe) and clear my browser cache for that site.  That fixed it.